# Getting a feed from a WP site

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering if anyone knows how we would go about pulling some kind of Wordpress feed to a html site? It's a syndicated process where the parent site will feed into multiple subdomains. We want to customize which categories and products are displayed on each subdomain. We could use MU wordpress with some sort of cron job plugin, but we were looking to try and make it more lightweight using an html site instead. Alternative to this could be Iframes, but we feed that that's a little limited.

Does anyone know how we'd do this? We want to be able to pull a feed from a wordpress site, and display on it on an html site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WP REST API for this or could use RSS XML Feeds

I have done this using REST API and is a far easier and convenient solution that RSS XML Feeds